# YouTube subscribe button shows Error

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I have this code

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" style="vertical-align: middle" data-channel="UCEXGDNclvmg6RW0vipJYsTQ"  data-count="default"></div>
```

The channel url is https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEXGDNclvmg6RW0vipJYsTQ

If I enter UCEXGDNclvmg6RW0vipJYsTQ in https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button it works

But on my page it does not - https://zoomthe.me/themeadmin-dzsvg/d/ - it shows **Error**

Any ideas ?

PS: By the way normal user channels work http://zoomthe.me/themeadmin-dzsvg/normal-user-subscribe/ - normal link http://youtube.com/user/digitalzoomstudio - so it has nothing to do with XSS

Comment: Have you checked your console errors? *hint X-XSS-Protection*

Comment: shows nothing - of course it's crosssite because it needs to link to youtube

Comment: I added Post scriptum

Comment: I see the same type of error on your site and on the google dev tool site you linked  (intermittently)  `Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.`

Answer (score 0):

Going to your site I see the below error in the console:

> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

This seems related to this [Google bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807304) which also states

> The fix for this landed in Chrome 66.0.3336.0.

The report also says this only happens when the `report` address isn't same origin (as in your case).

There are also users experiencing issues Youtube in the bug report as well.

Comment: Yeah, only thing is .. the bus is there in firefox too.

Comment: Hmm with Firefox I get a different error. `Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified

Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified

Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified`

Comment: @digitalzoomstudio you can try adding this meta tag at the top of your html page to allow scripts on your site to be loaded from https://apis.google.com and your own domain `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src https://apis.google.com 'self';">`

Comment: the recommended way is to include a `Content-Security-Policy` header in your server response, but you can see if the `<meta>` tag works

Comment: I get Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://apis.google.com 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-TsDB9xgClZNLIwDxWa2715v7A316yTL4JLUx3sY//pU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the console the error the error actually is an X-XSS protection error:

```
Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.
```

https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/288

It turns out that it is an error with chrome and it will be patched soon

> I don't think any further conversation is useful so I'm going to lock this. As @phpony pointed out, this is an issue with Chrome and not ReactPlayer. The bug is being tracked here – there is a fix in Chrome 66.0.3336.0 which is in Canary and so will be released in a stable build soon. The solution is just to be patient and wait for the next Chrome update.

(from CookPete https://github.com/CookPete)

After looking at the sources it looks like you are missing the

```
data-layout="default"
```

Comment: Yeah, only thing is .. the bus is there in firefox too.

Comment: @digitalzoomstudio , After looking at the raw sources it looks like you are missing the data-layout="default"

Comment: added , did not make any difference